# Como restar fechas en un query linq

Tags: c#, mvc, linq

Necesito que la resta now - a.DateLowStock sea >= a 14 dias. Como puedo hacerlo?

```
        ICollection<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now();

        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            products = (from a in db.Products
                        where now - a.DateLowStock >= "14 dias").ToList
        }
        return products;
    }
```

DateLowStock es DateTime? y donde dice "14 dias" es la condición que quiero que cumpla para agregarlo a la lista. En lugar de "14 dias", ¿que debería poner?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La resta de dos fechas, devuelve un [TimeSpan](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Lo cual es logico, porque la resta de dos fechas, es otra fecha, o en este caso, un intervalo de tiempo.

Esta estructura, tiene varias propiedades, y entre ellas, la que nos interesa en particular es [Days](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.days?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_TimeSpan_Days). Tene en cuenta, que este valor puede ser positivo o negativo.

Por lo tanto, en tu linq, podemos (y debemos) hacer algo asi:

```
((TimeSpan)(now - a.DateLowStock)).Days >= 14
```

Ahora, si te preguntas porque todo ese lio de parentesis, es para hacer la conversion correcta a la hora de restar los datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

En linq tienes que usar las `SqlFunctions`

[SqlFunctions.DateDiff Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datediff?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_Objects_SqlClient_SqlFunctions_DateDiff_System_String_System_Nullable_System_DateTime__System_Nullable_System_DateTime__)

algo como esto

```
products = (from a in db.Products
             where SqlFunctions.DateDiff("DAY", now, a.DateLowStock) >= 14).ToList()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Solo para clarificar que es en LinqToSql o Entity Framework donde se requieren. En Linq en general no es necesario.